# count the urls in a column and update the value of the column with the number of urls in sql server

Tags: sql

[image]i have a list of form responses from goolge forms(including file uplaod urls), i am importing the google sheet into my sql server. some of the columns have multiple urls and some have a single url ( from the file upload control in google form).
i want to count the number of urls in each column and update the column with the numeral corresponding to the number of urls, e.g a column with name A1 has 3 file uploads so it has 3 urls, i want to count them and update it as numeral 3 for this particular row.
i want to do this to the whole table where each column (A1 TO A10 ) have a single value, multiple values, or a null ( where i should update 0). I have 6000+ responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A1,A2,A3......An,b.cnt  from TABLE_NAME a, (SELECT count(value) cnt FROM STRING_SPLIT(a.A1, 'https://drive')) b
```

try this query I think it should works